# Can't reference a script that is loaded as a component on a GameObject in a different script that is also loaded as a component on same GameObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm using a plugin to put a built Volumetric Light Beam into my scene.

I'd like to control the intensity of the light through another script that is triggering the intensity to go up and down (visually looking as if it's turning off and on, in other words, flickering).

My desired outcome is essentially turning the light off and on but without disabling the object so I can have the light animate its rotation while the light intensity is controlled by a separate script.

I'm fairly new to coding and haven't been writing any code for the last 3 months so it's a bit confusing just getting back in.

I have a light GameObject called Spotlight and Beam. Loaded on that GameObject is the Volumetric Dust Particles script (along with the other related scripts from the plugin).
[Heres an image of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gPMc.png)

I have another script loaded on this object called SpotlightFlicker. I'd like to use that to control the intensity property (that you can see is highlighted in the image above).

I thought that if the scripts were in the same folder(which I moved all the plugin scripts to the Unity scripts folder for this), I'd be able to reference the other script that is loaded as a component on the same GameObject using something like

public VolumetricLightBeam FlickeringSpotlight;

however, this appears:

> The type or namespace name 'VolumetricLightBeam' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)

The VolumetricLightBeam script is written quite differently than I've seen so far using Unity (in my beginner stages).

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace VLB
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [DisallowMultipleComponent]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(VolumetricLightBeam))]
    [HelpURL(Consts.Help.UrlDustParticles)]
    public class VolumetricDustParticles : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public const string ClassName = "VolumetricDustParticles";

        /// <summary>
        /// Max alpha of the particles
        /// </summary>
        [Range(0f, 1f)]
        public float alpha = Consts.DustParticles.AlphaDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// Max size of the particles
        /// </summary>
        [Range(0.0001f, 0.1f)]
        public float size = Consts.DustParticles.SizeDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// Direction of the particles.
        /// </summary>
        public ParticlesDirection direction = Consts.DustParticles.DirectionDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// Movement speed of the particles.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 velocity = Consts.DustParticles.VelocityDefault;

        [System.Obsolete("Use 'velocity' instead")]
        public float speed = 0.03f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Control how many particles are spawned. The higher the density, the more particles are spawned, the higher the performance cost is.
        /// </summary>
        public float density = Consts.DustParticles.DensityDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// The distance range (from the light source) where the particles are spawned.
        /// - Min bound: the higher it is, the more the particles are spawned away from the light source.
        /// - Max bound: the lower it is, the more the particles are gathered near the light source.
        /// </summary>
        [MinMaxRange(0.0f, 1.0f)]
        public MinMaxRangeFloat spawnDistanceRange = Consts.DustParticles.SpawnDistanceRangeDefault;

        [System.Obsolete("Use 'spawnDistanceRange' instead")]
        public float spawnMinDistance = 0f;

        [System.Obsolete("Use 'spawnDistanceRange' instead")]
        public float spawnMaxDistance = 0.7f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Enable particles culling based on the distance to the Main Camera.
        /// We highly recommend to enable this feature to keep good runtime performances.
        /// </summary>
        public bool cullingEnabled = Consts.DustParticles.CullingEnabledDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// If culling is enabled, the particles will not be rendered if they are further than cullingMaxDistance to the Main Camera.
        /// </summary>
        public float cullingMaxDistance = Consts.DustParticles.CullingMaxDistanceDefault;

        /// <summary>
        /// Is the particle system currently culled (no visible) because too far from the main camera?
        /// </summary>
        public bool isCulled { get; private set; }


        [SerializeField] float m_AlphaAdditionalRuntime = 1.0f;
        public float alphaAdditionalRuntime
        {
            get { return m_AlphaAdditionalRuntime; }
            set { if (m_AlphaAdditionalRuntime != value) { m_AlphaAdditionalRuntime = value; m_RuntimePropertiesDirty = true; } }
        }

        public bool particlesAreInstantiated { get { return m_Particles; } }
        public int particlesCurrentCount { get { return m_Particles ? m_Particles.particleCount : 0; } }
        public int particlesMaxCount { get { return m_Particles ? m_Particles.main.maxParticles : 0; } }
        ParticleSystem m_Particles = null;
        ParticleSystemRenderer m_Renderer = null;
        Material m_Material = null;
        Gradient m_GradientCached = new Gradient();
        bool m_RuntimePropertiesDirty = true;


        /// <summary>Cached version of Camera.main, for performance reasons</summary>
        public Camera mainCamera
        {
            get
            {
                if (!ms_MainCamera)
                {
                    ms_MainCamera = Camera.main;
                    if (!ms_MainCamera && !ms_NoMainCameraLogged)
                    {
                        Debug.LogErrorFormat(gameObject, "In order to use '" + VolumetricDustParticles.ClassName + "' culling, you must have a MainCamera defined in your scene.");
                        ms_NoMainCameraLogged = true;
                    }
                }

                return ms_MainCamera;
            }
        }

        // Cache the main camera, because accessing Camera.main at each frame is very bad performance-wise
        static bool ms_NoMainCameraLogged = false;
        static Camera ms_MainCamera = null;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        void OnValidate()
        {
            density = Mathf.Clamp(density, Consts.DustParticles.DensityMin, Consts.DustParticles.DensityMax);
            cullingMaxDistance = Mathf.Max(cullingMaxDistance, Consts.DustParticles.CullingMaxDistanceMin);
            Play(); // support instant refresh when modifying properties from inspector
        }
#endif // UNITY_EDITOR

        VolumetricLightBeam m_Master = null;

        void Start()
        {
            isCulled = false;

            m_Master = GetComponent<VolumetricLightBeam>();
            Debug.Assert(m_Master);
            HandleBackwardCompatibility(m_Master._INTERNAL_pluginVersion, Version.Current);

            InstantiateParticleSystem();

            SetActiveAndPlay();
        }

        void InstantiateParticleSystem()
        {
            // If we duplicate (from Editor and Playmode) the VLB, the children are also duplicated (like the dust particles)
            // we have to make sure to properly destroy them before creating our proper procedural particle instance.
            var slaves = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>(true);
            for (int i = slaves.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                DestroyImmediate(slaves[i].gameObject);

            m_Particles = Config.Instance.NewVolumetricDustParticles();

            if (m_Particles)
            {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                if (m_Master)
                {
                    UnityEditor.GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(m_Particles.gameObject, m_Master.GetStaticEditorFlagsForSubObjects());
                    m_Particles.gameObject.SetSameSceneVisibilityStatesThan(m_Master.gameObject);
                }
#endif // UNITY_EDITOR
                m_Particles.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
                m_Particles.transform.localRotation = m_Master.beamInternalLocalRotation;

                m_Renderer = m_Particles.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
                Debug.Assert(m_Renderer);

                m_Material = new Material(m_Renderer.sharedMaterial);
                Debug.Assert(m_Material);
                m_Renderer.material = m_Material;
            }
        }

        void OnEnable()
        {
            SetActiveAndPlay();
        }
        
        void SetActive(bool active)
        {
            if (m_Particles) m_Particles.gameObject.SetActive(active);
        }

        void SetActiveAndPlay()
        {
            SetActive(true);
            Play();
        }

        void Play()
        {
            if (m_Particles)
            {
                SetParticleProperties();
                m_Particles.Simulate(0f);
                m_Particles.Play(true);
            }
        }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            SetActive(false);
        }

        void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (m_Particles)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(m_Particles.gameObject); // Make sure to delete the GAO
                m_Particles = null;
            }

            if (m_Material)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(m_Material);
                m_Material = null;
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if(!Application.isPlaying)
            {
                if (m_Particles == null)
                    InstantiateParticleSystem();

                Play();
            }
            else
#endif // UNITY_EDITOR
            {
                UpdateCulling();

                Debug.Assert(m_Master);
                if (m_Master.trackChangesDuringPlaytime)
                    SetParticleProperties();
            }

            if (m_RuntimePropertiesDirty && m_Material != null)
            {
                m_Material.SetColor(ShaderProperties.ParticlesTintColor, new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alphaAdditionalRuntime));
                m_RuntimePropertiesDirty = false;
            }
        }

        void SetParticleProperties()
        {
            if (m_Particles && m_Particles.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                var thickness = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - (m_Master.fresnelPow / Consts.Beam.FresnelPowMaxValue));
                
                var coneLength = m_Master.fallOffEnd * (spawnDistanceRange.maxValue - spawnDistanceRange.minValue);
                var ratePerSec = coneLength * density;
                int maxParticles = (int)(ratePerSec * 4);

                var main = m_Particles.main;

                var startLifetime = main.startLifetime;
                startLifetime.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.TwoConstants;
                startLifetime.constantMin = 4f;
                startLifetime.constantMax = 6f;
                main.startLifetime = startLifetime;

                var startSize = main.startSize;
                startSize.mode = ParticleSystemCurveMode.TwoConstants;
                startSize.constantMin = size * 0.9f;
                startSize.constantMax = size * 1.1f;
                main.startSize = startSize;
                
                var startColor = main.startColor;

                if (m_Master.usedColorMode == ColorMode.Flat)
                {
                    startColor.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.Color;
                    var colorMax = m_Master.color;
                    colorMax.a *= alpha;
                    startColor.color = colorMax;
                }
                else
                {
                    startColor.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.Gradient;

                    // Duplicate gradient and apply alpha
                    var gradientRef = m_Master.colorGradient;
                    var colorKeys = gradientRef.colorKeys;
                    var alphaKeys = gradientRef.alphaKeys;

                    for(int i=0; i< alphaKeys.Length; ++i)
                        alphaKeys[i].alpha *= alpha;

                    Debug.Assert(m_GradientCached != null);
                    m_GradientCached.SetKeys(colorKeys, alphaKeys);
                    startColor.gradient = m_GradientCached;
                }
                main.startColor = startColor;

                {
                    var startSpeed = main.startSpeed;
                    startSpeed.constant = (direction == ParticlesDirection.Random) ? Mathf.Abs(velocity.z) : 0.0f;
                    main.startSpeed = startSpeed;
                }

                {
                    var velocityOverLifetime = m_Particles.velocityOverLifetime;
                    velocityOverLifetime.enabled = (direction != ParticlesDirection.Random);
                    velocityOverLifetime.space = (direction == ParticlesDirection.LocalSpace) ? ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local : ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World;
                    velocityOverLifetime.xMultiplier = velocity.x;
                    velocityOverLifetime.yMultiplier = velocity.y;
                    velocityOverLifetime.zMultiplier = velocity.z;
                }

                main.maxParticles = maxParticles;

                {
                    var shape = m_Particles.shape;
                    shape.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.ConeVolume;

                    float coneAngle = m_Master.coneAngle * Mathf.Lerp(0.7f, 1f, thickness);
                    shape.angle = coneAngle * 0.5f;

                    float radiusStart = m_Master.coneRadiusStart * Mathf.Lerp(0.3f, 1.0f, thickness);
                    float radiusEnd = Utils.ComputeConeRadiusEnd(m_Master.fallOffEnd, coneAngle);
                    shape.radius = Mathf.Lerp(radiusStart, radiusEnd, spawnDistanceRange.minValue);

                    shape.length = coneLength;

                    var localOffset = m_Master.fallOffEnd * spawnDistanceRange.minValue;
#if UNITY_2017_1_OR_NEWER
                    shape.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, localOffset);
#else
                    m_Particles.transform.localPosition = m_Master.beamLocalForward * localOffset;
#endif
                    shape.arc = 360f;
                    shape.randomDirectionAmount = (direction == ParticlesDirection.Random) ? 1f : 0f;
                }

                var emission = m_Particles.emission;
                var rate = emission.rateOverTime;
                rate.constant = ratePerSec;
                emission.rateOverTime = rate;

                if(m_Renderer)
                {
                    m_Renderer.sortingLayerID = m_Master.sortingLayerID;
                    m_Renderer.sortingOrder = m_Master.sortingOrder;
                }
            }
        }

        void HandleBackwardCompatibility(int serializedVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            if (serializedVersion == -1) return;            // freshly new spawned entity: nothing to do
            if (serializedVersion == newVersion) return;    // same version: nothing to do

#pragma warning disable 0618
            if (serializedVersion < 1880)
            {
                // Version 1880 changed the order of ParticlesDirection enum and add WorldSpace option
                if ((int)direction == 0)    direction = (ParticlesDirection)1;
                else                        direction = (ParticlesDirection)0;

                // Version 1880 changed from single float speed to 3D velocity vector
                velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speed);
            }

            if (serializedVersion < 1940)
            {
                spawnDistanceRange = new MinMaxRangeFloat(spawnMinDistance, spawnMaxDistance);
            }
#pragma warning restore 0618

            Utils.MarkCurrentSceneDirty();
        }

        #region Culling
        void UpdateCulling()
        {
            if (m_Particles)
            {
                bool visible = true;
                if ((cullingEnabled || m_Master.isFadeOutEnabled) && m_Master.hasGeometry)
                {
                    if (mainCamera)
                    {
                        var maxDist = cullingMaxDistance;
                        if (m_Master.isFadeOutEnabled) maxDist = Mathf.Min(maxDist, m_Master.fadeOutEnd);
                        var maxDistSqr = maxDist * maxDist;
                        var distSqr = m_Master.bounds.SqrDistance(mainCamera.transform.position);
                        visible = distSqr <= maxDistSqr;
                    }
                    else
                        cullingEnabled = false;
                }

                if (m_Particles.gameObject.activeSelf != visible)
                {
                    SetActive(visible);
                    isCulled = !visible;
                }

                if (visible && !m_Particles.isPlaying)
                    m_Particles.Play();
            }
        } 
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Can anyone here help me understand how to reference this other script and also control the intensity variable? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the type name is `VLB.VolumetricLightBeam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the needed namespace using at the top of your script (i suppose it is `VLB`) like

```
using System;
using VLB; // add this line
```

The script you want to add is in another namespace, so you need to tell your script, where to find it before you are able to work with it. Tools like ReSharper for VisualStudio (or Rider IDE that included the same functionality) help a lot with such cases.

Comment: Thanks so much, Morion! Appreciate the help. Totally was the issue. Downloading ReSharper now too! Great advice!